# Finding a mirror node in a binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, debugging, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to find the mirror node of a node in a binary tree. The problem is  [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/trees/binary-and-nary-trees/practice-problems/algorithm/mirror-image-2/description/).  Here the insertion is random and to connect two nodes we need to check if it is already in the tree or not. So, I made a dynamic array of nodes to store the pointers of the respective data elements.

My problem is whenever I display the elements it's showing root is null. However, I already initialized the root with '1'. I think the problem is somewhere in the insertion function but unable to find where is it.

The function for insertion:

```
void insert(int x, int y , char ch)
{
node* temp = NULL;
node* temp1 = NULL;
cout << "ptr[x]is: " << ptr[x]->data << "\n";
/*
    The root is initialized with 1 
    then also the code is going inside the if condition
    I don't know why this is happening.
*/
if(ptr[x] == NULL)
{
    temp = new node;
    temp->data = x;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
}
else
    temp = ptr[x];
if(ptr[y] == NULL)
{
    temp1 = new node;
    temp1->data = y;
    temp1->left = temp1->right = NULL;
}
else
    temp1 = ptr[y];
ch == 'R'? temp->right = temp1: temp->left = temp1;
}
```

The link for original code: [my code link](https://ideone.com/T1v1V9)

Comment: So what have you found out by debugging yet?

Comment: root is NULL, Even after insertion.